# ReactJS - Access key of container div on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, redux

Here is the code that I'm working on right now.

How can I access the key that I have on the container `div`? Right now I'm just trying to console.log it but ultimately, I need to pass the `key` to an action so I can make a call to an API.

Thanks for any advice.

I want to access the key on the container div

```
 renderRecipes() {
  return _.map(this.props.recipes, recipe => {
   return (
    <div className="card" style={cardStyle}  key={recipe.idMeal}>
      <img className="card-img-top" src={recipe.strMealThumb} alt="Recipe" />
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{recipe.strMeal}</h5>
        <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={this.viewRecipe}>
          View Recipe Details
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
   )
 })
}

 render() {
  console.log(this.props.recipes);
   return (
    <div>
     <h2>Main Ingredient Search Page</h2>
     <SearchField />
     <div className="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
      {this.renderRecipes()}
     </div>
  </div>
);
 }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, I want the OnClick function on the button to be the trigger to fetch the key from the container div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it pretty easily with an anonymous function:

```
<button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={() => this.viewRecipe(recipe.mealId)}>
  View Recipe Details
</button>
```

But the best way would be to extract the recipe into it's own component. Then it's nicely encapsulated and doesn't re-render onclick references.

```
class Recipe extends Component {
  onViewDetails = () => {
    this.props.onItemClick(this.props.id);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      name,
      thumbnail
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="card" style={cardStyle}>
        <img className="card-img-top" src={thumbnail} alt="Recipe" />
        <div className="card-body">
          <h5 className="card-title">{name}</h5>
          <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={this.onViewDetails}>
            View Recipe Details
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

--

```
return _.map(this.props.recipes, recipe => (
  <Recipe
    key={recipe.idMeal}
    id={recipe.idMeal}
    thumbnail={recipe.strMealThumb}
    name={recipe.strMeal}
    onItemClick={this.viewRecipe}
  />
);
```

Comment: That tip is useful but is your code right? I think the button code should have `onClick={this.onViewDetails}` right?

Comment: This solution (i.e. the anonymous function) worked for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this

```
renderRecipes() {
  return this.props.recipes.map(recipe => {
   return (
    <div className="card" style={cardStyle}  key={recipe.idMeal}>
      <img className="card-img-top" src={recipe.strMealThumb} alt="Recipe" />
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{recipe.strMeal}</h5>
        <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={() => this.viewRecipe(recipe.idMeal)}>
          View Recipe Details
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
   )
 })
}
```

Now, in the onClick function you'll receive the key!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define your `viewRecipe` method in this way:

```
viewRecipe = recipe => e => console.log(recipe)
```

`viewRecipe` will be a function that receives a **recipe** as parameter and returns another function which will be used for the `onClick` method:

```
<button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={this.viewRecipe(recipe)}>
```

Or you can use also the [techniques](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers) described in the docs which are the following:

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>
<button onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this, id)}>Delete Row</button>
```